# How to not call onChange method of input when there is white-spaces but call when string is deleted as left only a empty string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Actually I want to implement a search function in which the result is based on the api response. So when user type something i.e. onChange function call, the api is called. I am trimming the string so that no extra white spaces are passes to api function call. Also I have added condition that trimmed string length > 0, if that condition met then I am calling the api, but the problem which this approach is that when the user press backspace and the string get empty the api is not calling, as the string length is 0, but I want to call the api when string length is 0 but only when string length = 0 is achieved through backspaces or string deletion.

Could somebody help me how to implement onChange as per my use case.

Below is the short dummy implementation of code.

```
<TextField value={this.state.searchString} onChange={_onChangeHandler}/>
```

```
function _onChangeHandler(event){
    this.setState({searchString:event.target.value});
    //api call which return response of search ;
    if(event.target.value.trim().length > 0){
        searchAPI(event.target.value.trim());
    }
}
```

Since I have added condition of length > 0 , so I will not call searchApi() when user type something and the remove or delete the typed string. But I wnat to call searchAPI function whenever user delete the typed string or remove is through backspaces till string becomes empty.

Comment: You are thing in a wrong way. Wrong way to achieve this

Comment: You need to show what are you doing with code.

Comment: @iwaduarte added some more details

Comment: You are also very confusing.  I can not understand what you are trying to do.
Do you want to call the api exactly when?  Please convey concrete example as:
`const callAPI= "aaaaa"
const doNotCallAPI= "      "
const errorShouldCallButIsNotCalling= ?`

Answer (score -1):

One way you could design your onChange function is by keeping track if a user as input a value or not.

So the function could be something like.

```
function onChangeHandler(value){
     let isValueDirty = false; // dirty value means that the user has entered or previously entered something. 
     ... change the value of isValueDirty to true when user enters something. 
     ... modify your value.length check to 
     if(value.length === 0 && isValueDirty) {
     ... call API.
      }

}
```

Comment: since length is always zero it will never call the API when user has input something.

Comment: Why would the length always be zero?
Either way, you have to keep track of whether the value is dirty or not.